# AWS CloudFormation template generation issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have AWS Lambda service running which I had developed and deployed using the AWS SAM CLI. There are some other services as like ElasticCache, RDS, etc running in my AWS Account.

Now my requirement is to generate the CloudFormation YAML template file out of existing running service which I can use to provision later and keep as a backup. For this, I used CloudFormer template however problem is that CloudFormer does not consider or generate YAML template for AWS Lambda services which I had noticed. And also I believe CloudFormer has become obsolete as well.

Please assist me here to let me know if there any latest service from AWS that can fulfil my requirement here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation supports the creation of stacks from existing resources.

Take a further look: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-new-stack.html

Comment: Thanks, will it consider my existing Lambda service as well?

Comment: Hi, yes this is for any CloudFormation based resource as far as I am aware. Lambdas are a key part of AWS so would definitely be supported

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is **no such functionality**, apart from `CloudFormer` which is not maintained anymore by AWS nor reliable (in beta for years).

To use the [importing resources feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html) into CFN, you have to **manually write** its template. This means you prepare your templates for RDS or EC, which match exactly your existing resources. If you have written the yaml or json template for the imported resources, you then can attempt to import them. In other words, the feature **does not generate yaml** code for you.

Maybe there are some non-AWS third party tools for that, but I'm not aware of any worth recommending unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There is an opensource replacement for Cloudformer named former2 at https://github.com/iann0036/former2.  I believe it can work as both a chrome/firefox addon and a cli tool.